# Area integral of an ellipse in polar coordinates

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, conic-sections, polar-coordinates

I have two questions: one related to evaluating the integral and the other related to how area in general is evaluated in polar coordinates.

---

(1) The area of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ written in Cartesian Coordinates is 4 times the integral $\int_0^a \frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$ and is equal to $\pi a b$.

The standard equation of an ellipse in polar coordinates is $r=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+ e\cos \theta}$, ($e$ is the eccentricity). The area (which is given by $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}r^2 d\theta$) would then be:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2(1-e^2)^2}{(1+e \cos \theta)^2} d\theta$$
This might seem to diverge but (fortunately) it does not as $0<e<1$ for an ellipse. But I don't seem to be able to evaluate this integral and  I'm interested in knowing how.

(2) I put it in [integral-calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) and it says "integral is divergent" because I don't know how to put the condition $0<e<1$. I tried replacing $e$ with $\sqrt{1-a^2}$ to satisfy that condition (as we're doing it in real domain) and  integrated $\dfrac{1}{\left(1+ \sqrt{1-a^2}\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)^2}$ w.r.t $\theta$ and found the antiderivative to be:
$$\dfrac{2\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-a^2}}\sqrt{\sqrt{1-a^2}+1}\ \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-a^2}}\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\sqrt{1-a^2}+1}}\right)}{a^4}-\dfrac{\sqrt{1-a^2}\sin\left(\theta\right)}{a^2\cdot\left(\sqrt{1-a^2}\cos\left(\theta\right)+1\right)}\tag1$$

Now, from my understanding, in polar coordinates we don't need to split the area into different quadrants like we do in Cartesian (to avoid the negative areas canceling positive ones) due to the way the area integral is derived in polar coordinates. But, when we put in the bounds $0$ and $2\pi$ in expression (1), we get zero.

Please explain.

Comment: The change of variable $x=a\cos \theta$ should transform the second integral into the first.

Comment: But $x=r \cos\theta = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \cos\theta$ . How is $x=a \cos\theta$ justified? @GiuseppeNegro

Comment: Mathematica gives: $$\int{dt\over(1+e\cos t)^2}=\frac{e \sin (t)}{\left(e^2-1\right) (e \cos (t)+1)}-\frac{2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{(e-1)
   \tan \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{e^2-1}}\right)}{\left(e^2-1\right)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: You can transform it into a rational integral with the substitution $u=\tan(\theta/2)$.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems like it would run into the same problem I had in part (2). When we plug in the bounds $0$and $2\pi$ (or even $0$and $\pi$) into that we'll get zero. I'm confused (reply to the integral comment)

Comment: I mean, how did you pass to polar coordinates? The same map that gives the equation of the ellipse in polar coordinates must transform the Cartesian area integral into the polar one.

Comment: That polar equation was not "derived" from the Cartesian one, however we could... after shifting the Cartesian one's right focus to the origin. But the graphs of the Cartesian and polar equations stated in my post above are not the same ellipse. Also my question is about evaluating the integral so... I'm not sure if I should.

Comment: That antiderivative is not written in the simplest way (typical of Mathematica). The second term can be recasted in the following form: $$-{2\tanh^{−1}\left((−1)\tan(/2)\over\sqrt{^2−1}\right)\over(^2−1)^{3/2}}={2\over(1-^2)^{3/2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-\over1+}\tan{\over2}\right).$$ As $t\to\pi^-$ the $\tan^{-1}$ tends to $\pi/2$ and everything goes in place.